# Undefined reference to overloaded operator inside of namespace

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble using an overloaded operator that's declared inside of a namespace.

The setup looks like this:

**classa.h**

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

namespace ns1 {

class ClassA {
public:
  ClassA();

  enum class MyEnum : unsigned {
    VAL_A = 0,
    VAL_B = 1,
    VAL_C = 2,
    VAL_D = 4,
    VAL_E = 8
  };
};

// Declaration of overloaded operator
ClassA::MyEnum operator|(ClassA::MyEnum const &lhs, ClassA::MyEnum const &rhs);

} // namespace ns1

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

**classa.cpp**

```
#include "classa.h"

using ns1::ClassA;

ClassA::ClassA() {}

// Definition of overloaded operator
ClassA::MyEnum operator|(ClassA::MyEnum const &lhs, ClassA::MyEnum const &rhs) {
  return static_cast<ClassA::MyEnum>(static_cast<unsigned>(lhs) |
                                     static_cast<unsigned>(rhs));
};
```

and **main.cpp**

```
#include "classa.h"
#include <iostream>

using ns1::ClassA;

int main() {
  auto temp{ClassA::MyEnum::VAL_A | ClassA::MyEnum::VAL_B};
  std::cout << (unsigned)temp << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler produces:

```
error: undefined reference to `ns1::operator|(ns1::ClassA::MyEnum const&, ns1::ClassA::MyEnum const&)'
```

How can I use the definition of the overloaded operator in my program?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: The compiler is clang++ 11

Comment: Your `classa.cpp` defines `::operator|`, which is unrelated to `ns1::operator|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *define* the operator in the same namespace that it's *declared* in, otherwise you have two different, unrelated operators (one of which is undefined, and the other only defined in `classa.cpp`).

Just wrap the entire implementation in a `namespace ns1` block:

**classa.cpp**

```cpp
#include "classa.h"

namespace ns1 {

ClassA::ClassA() {}

// Definition of overloaded operator
ClassA::MyEnum operator|(ClassA::MyEnum const &lhs, ClassA::MyEnum const &rhs) {
  return static_cast<ClassA::MyEnum>(static_cast<unsigned>(lhs) |
                                     static_cast<unsigned>(rhs));
};

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`using ns1::ClassA` doesn't do what you expect. It only propagates ns1::ClassA id to global namespace but it doesn't affect definitions following it. `operator|` should be defined in `ns1` scope.

```
namespace ns1 {
// Definition of overloaded operator
ClassA::MyEnum operator|(ClassA::MyEnum const &lhs, ClassA::MyEnum const &rhs) {
  return static_cast<ClassA::MyEnum>(static_cast<unsigned>(lhs) |
                                     static_cast<unsigned>(rhs));
};
}
```

Comment: thanks, this also is quite helpful, the explanation of the actual effect of 'using'. Cheers